# video not smooth in video loop HTML in ionic2 angular2

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I have a video player in my angular2 ionic2 app.

I am playing 4 seconds video 7 times in HTML video tag with loop attribute.

It is playing well in loop, but there is minor flickering in playing video in loop. i.e it have small pause in loop, when the video completes and start play again.

Following is my html code here :

```
<video id="video1" width="100%" poster="img/aImg.jpg"
                   class="vid-background"
                   autoplay loop>
                   <source src={{myVideo}} type="video/mp4">
            </video>
```

The **myVideo** is the video url. It is playing well in the browser but in my ionic2 angular2 code, it have issue.

Please suggest why it have small pause. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still waiting for the answer..